# Как добавить несколько Меню в API Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, api

у меня получилось добавить меню в АПИ с помощью этого кода, но мне нужно добавить неслько меню на сайте, как это сделать ?
Вот пример с одним меню

```
function get_menu() {
    // Replace your menu name, slug or ID carefully
    return wp_get_nav_menu_items('menu');
}

add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'wp/v2', 'menu', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'get_menu',
    ) );
} );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не совсем понятно, вам это надо в рамках одного запроса или нескольких. Вот код, который возвращает все нужные меню в рамках одного запроса `wp/v2/menus`:

```
/**
 * Get site menus.
 *
 * @return array|false
 */
function get_menus() {
    $menu_names = [
        'menu',
        'menu2',
    ];

    $menus = [];
    foreach ( $menu_names as $menu_name ) {
        $menus[ $menu_name ] = wp_get_nav_menu_items( $menu_name );
    }

    return $menus;
}

add_action(
    'rest_api_init',
    function () {
        register_rest_route(
            'wp/v2',
            'menus',
            [
                'methods'  => 'GET',
                'callback' => 'get_menus',
            ]
        );
    }
);
```

Список меню укажите в массиве `$menu_names`.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, это то что нужно!